# How to design rest end point for an item having multiple types?

Tags: java, rest

I currently have some end points for notifications:

> Create/Update: `POST /notifications` and params: `SimpleNotif` pojo
>
> Get Notifs (listing): `POST /notifications/query` and params: `NotifFilter` pojo
>
> Get Notif: `GET /notifications/{id}` and params: `id` of
>   simple notif
>
> Delete Notif: `DELETE /notifications/{id}` and params: id again

The `NotifFilter` pojo has fields like `sortBy`, `offset`, `limit`  etc. Now notifications are of two types: simple and composite (aka summary). The above rest end points are used for simple notifications.

The POJOs `SimpleNotif` and `SummaryNotif` share lots of attributes as well. A summary notification will have all the same attributes (e.g. name, frequency etc.) along with a list of simple notifications. The summary notification can be triggered based on certain rules e.g. severity of one notification changes or multiple changes etc.

How to handle rest end point design for CRUD for the summary notifications ?

```
/notifications/summary
```

will conflict with

```
/notifications/{id}.
```

The existing end points take a filter object for filtering, should I introduce type there? I don't think introducing a completely new rest end point is desirable as we already have one for notifications. Any suggestions how to handle CRUD for summarynotif?

**Side Note:** The reason for using POST for listing ( a GET actually) is URL length restriction in browser.

Answer (score 1):

> The existing end points take a filter object for filtering, should I
>   introduce type there?

Yes, that would make sense with your current implementation, since considering the `SummaryNotif` is just a type of notification. So in future, if you introduce another type, you cannot just add another endpoint for it.

An alternate way of doing the same was ***introducing a query param*** `?type=summary`(also for the fact that you're performing a `GET` under the name f `POST`), but since you already have a queryable endpoint, you shall reuse it with an additional parameter in your request object.

---

Another design suggestion would be that, you can create a parent (say `Notification`) out of `SummaryNotif` and `SimpleNotif` with esp. the attributes that are common to them, your basic CRUD could still look like :

```
Create/Update: POST /notifications and params: Accept a Notification object (subtyping helps here) 

Get Notifs (listing): POST /notifications/query and params: updated NotifFilter pojo

Get Notif: GET /notifications/{id} and params: id

Delete Notif: DELETE /notifications/{id} and params: id
```

Comment: But how would i handle create scenario which does not take filter and takes simplenotif pojo? How can I pass summarynotif?

Comment: @i_am_zero I think the edit I was making answers this. You shall create a parent object for such classes and use the concept like subtyping to expose generic APIs.

Comment: Even I thought of introducing inheritance but that may break the existing code where SimpleNotif is used freely. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion :) +1

Comment: Also imo it would have made more sense to have urls of form `notifications/simple` and `notifications/summary`. They would convey the resource in a better fashion. But not a possibility :(

Comment: @i_am_zero I think, in that case you might want to look at the design that has brought in such incompatibility.

Comment: The other option is to use a custom `Content-type`.

Comment: @nullpointer Though I agree with you about design choice but that is existing piece of code and is used at lot of places. So I thought of finding come clever solution with minimum change in design ;)

Comment: @nullpointer For subtyping I need to use ObjectMapper for de-serialization at rest api end?

Comment: @i_am_zero yes, you would mostly have to use an objectmapper for that.